# Is it possible to access return value of child components in a wrapping parent component with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent, children

i've a question about accessing child components return value in the render function of the wrapping parent component. I want to "manipulate" the child component appeareance ...

```
                <ResponsiveWrapper>
                    <PersonalData/>
                    <LoginData/>
                </ResponsiveWrapper>
```

**ResponsiveWrapper**

The problem is, that the children of ResponsiveWrapper in its render function are like this:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {}
ref: null
type: ƒ PersonalData()
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 0, key: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, stateNode: null, …}
_store: {validated: true}
_self: null
_source: null
__proto__: Object

$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {}
ref: null
type: ƒ LoginData()
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 0, key: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, stateNode: null, …}
_store: {validated: true}
_self: null
_source: null
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

... but i want this. I need the elements which are rendered by PersonalData and LoginData:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {head: "Akkordeon", right: {…}, children: Array(2), className: "", dataGroup: null, …}
ref: null
type: ƒ Accordion(props)
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 1, key: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, stateNode: App, …}
_store: {validated: true}
_self: null
_source: null
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wfkufq, you can use React.Children.map(() =>
        React.cloneElement(child, { }))  are you expecting something like this ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I've understood: you want to manipulate the DOM of the elements rendered in `PersonalData` and `LoginData`?